# IBM Worklight unwanted line on border during orientation change Ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am working on a project based on IBM worklight. I am getting some unwanted issue when i change device orientation(either landscape to portrait or portrait to landscape ) .The issue is it shows lines on page border .The color of lines is same as color of splash screen color.
I am using worklight 6.0 and testing on iphone/ipad devices.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Screen shots? Worklight version?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Worklight 6.0.0, update worklight with Fix Patch 1 and then update with Worklight Interim Fix , the interim fix has been specifically given for IOS 7.

You also need to update your Eclipse. Once updated, re-create the environment and hopefully it will resolve the problem.